# I am missing from Patent Inventor

Tags: us20140319036

In reference to the patent: [US20140319036](https://www.google.com/patents/US20140319036)

This patent is based on my work and I found my name missing from the list of inventors. The patent is issued in the USA, Europe and Korea.

I have all the proofs and related documents to prove my inventorship. I would highly appreciate if someone can guide me through the process so that the inventorship is corrected.

Comment: please specify the proof you have and how you are true inventor?

Comment: This is not issued but is a published application. If you have proof you could take the matter up with the assignee company Doosan.

Comment: Thanks for the reply Pushpak and Epicentre. I am currently following this with Doosan through a patent attorney. Hope we will be able to resolve the matter amicably.

Answer (score 1):

And, a simple Google search would have gave you this [answer](http://www.uspto.gov/web/offices/pac/mpep/s1412.html#d0e138159).

Now, according to this [resource](http://www.uspto.gov/web/offices/pac/mpep/s602.html#d0e4830ss602) you need to read the fine document, and file a reissue with the changes.